# Can I use regular bootstrap toast in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I tried to understand how to use toast, but I couldn't and that's why I'm looking for help here.
Is there a reason why to use react-bootstrap over regular bootstrap? I start to think that I cannot use all functionalities from regular bootstrap in react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use all the plain bootstrap utilities in React, but it is not reccomended.

This is because to enable interactive functionality, Bootstrap uses JQuery and other DOM-altering Javascript, which doesn't always play that well with React, which likes to "own" the DOM and any alterations.

---

If you check out the Usage section of the Bootstrap Toasts docs ([here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/toasts/#usage)), you can see that it toasts need to be initialised with Jquery/JS:

> Initialize toasts via JavaScript:
>
> `$('.toast').toast(option)`

This can be messy to place within React, there are ways of calling it inside a `useEffect()` block but I've had trouble with similar things in the past.

---

This is why react-bootstrap is great, it can give you pre-made components with all this functionality baked in, which you can just drop into your codebase.

See the react-bootstrap docs for toasts [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/toasts/), fullly funcitonal toasts can be added with just:

```
<Toast>
  <Toast.Header>
     <strong className="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
  </Toast.Header>
  <Toast.Body>Hello, world! This is a toast message.</Toast.Body>
</Toast>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I now understand better

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which version of Bootstrap you're using. **Bootstrap 5 no longer uses jQuery** so Bootstrap components like the Toast can be used *without* the need for a 3rd party library like `react-bootstrap` or `reactstrap`.

First import the desired components...

```
import { Toast } from 'bootstrap';
```

Then, instantiate and use as needed...

```
const { Toast } = bootstrap;

var toastEl = document.getElementById('myToast');
const bsToast = new Toast(toastEl);
bsToast.show();
```

[Bootstrap 5 Toast with React](https://codeply.com/p/xlyhpHyRHr)